# Maximum call stack size exceeded, trying to make counting up value in my div

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

trying to make changing innerText in my div from 0 to value in div.
Can you tell me - why call stack size exceeded, I tried to create condition to leave my recurssion - but it doesnt'work

```
const itemsToCount = document.querySelectorAll('.customers'); 


function counter (item) {
    let stopPoint = Number(item.innerText.slice(0,-1));
    let counterNum = 0; 
    function increase () {  
        if (counterNum === stopPoint) {
            item.innerText = `${item}+`
            return; 
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                item.innerText = counterNum; 
                
            }, 100)
            counterNum += 1;
            return increase(); 
        }
        
    }
    increase()
}

Array.from(itemsToCount).forEach(item => {
    counter(item)
})
```

my HTML looks like

```
                 <div class="wrapper">
                      <p class="experience__counter customers">250+</p>
                      <p class="experience__counter customers">20+</p>
                      <p class="experience__counter customers">150+</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of _how_ those values are meant to change? Are they just meant to increase every 10th of a second?

Comment: your code doesn't fail like that for me. However, you have a fundamental flaw in your logic - the code won't wait for setTimeout to complete, therefore by the time `item.innerText = counterNum;` is called (every tenth of a second) - counterNum is already at its maximum value for that node

Comment: But, I stress that there is no stack size exceeded error (perhaps your real counters have much higher values)

Comment: yeah, every 10th of a second value should be changed in my div on page. 
and this "loop" stops when it reaches value from html.

Comment: try putting `counterNum += 1; increase();` INSIDE the setTimeout callback

Comment: yeah, it works, thank you very much. add it please to answer and i'll approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"try putting counterNum += 1; increase(); INSIDE the setTimeout callback"
Bravo 2 days ago

thank you, https://stackoverflow.com/users/10549313/bravo

Answer (score 0):

Hey according to me querySelectorAll returns a collection so you can't change its innerText like this. You have to use this -- itemsToCount[0]
here 0 is the index try using this

Comment: That's already in the code posted in the question, where the `Array.from()` is.